# Determine which options OpenSSH was compiled with?

Tags: linux, openssh, ldflags, cflags

I want to upgrade `openssh-server` from source code. I have a problem on how to find out what options `OpenSSH` was compiled with.

How can I determine which options OpenSSH was compiled with?

Comment: I know just uninstall old version ,And install new one. I just have question about finding what options Openssh was compiled with.

Comment: Which distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any place where it would be stored in the packaged binaries. But if you are using some opensource operating system (you should, if you got the compiled packages of OpenSSH), you should be able to get source packages (SRPM, DEB), which contain the recipes to build the package with all the switches and patches used.

For example Fedora spec file can be found [here](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/openssh.git/tree/openssh.spec#n542). Similarly, there are Debian flags to be found in their [repository](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/debian/rules) (harder to read).